# Use tcl variables in a shell script

Tags: shell, tcl

I have a tcl file with some variables set. I want to source this tcl file into my shell script to use them there.

When I do source `<filename>.tcl`, and echo the variable, it complains saying variable not found. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [this page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/37802) for more info about how to use tcl in shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ... convoluted

Here's Tcl script that sets a variable:

```
$ cat > vars.tcl
set var "this is a Tcl value"
```

Let's see if we can get Tcl to output that in shell syntax:

```
$ echo 'source vars.tcl; foreach _v {var} {puts "$_v=\"[set $_v]\""}' | tclsh
var="this is a Tcl value"
```

So far so good. Now, with bash:

```
$ echo "${var:-var is unset}"
var is unset
$ . <(echo 'source vars.tcl; foreach _v {var} {puts "$_v=\"[set $_v]\""}' | tclsh)
$ echo "${var:-var is unset}"
this is a Tcl value
```

with if you're using plain /bin/sh

```
$ echo "${var:-var is unset}"
var is unset
$ . <(echo 'source vars.tcl; foreach _v {var} {puts "$_v=\"[set $_v]\""}' | tclsh)
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
$ eval "$(echo 'source vars.tcl; foreach _v {var} {puts "$_v=\"[set $_v]\""}' | tclsh)"
$ echo "${var:-var is unset}"
this is a Tcl value
```

This assumes that your Tcl script does nothing beyond setting variables, or that you're OK with sourcing it to get the variables set; and the variable values do not contain double quotes.

Comment: Note that apostrophe characters in the value will cause trouble. Indeed, shells aren't nearly as binary safe as Tcl, and the space of permitted variable names is smaller too...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use tcl variables in a shell script. Even though `source` seems to work, it is not going to do what you think it does. When you use the `source` command from a shell script, it will attempt to interpret the contents of the file as a shell script.

Comment: So in order to access the variables, I would need another shell script or would have to define the variables again here?

Comment: @DivyaGuruvayurappan: I don't understand that question. You can't define variables in a tcl script and access them from a shell script. Without knowing what the actual problem is you're trying to solve it's hard to give any better advice.